# Camera orientation and preview size

Tags: java, android, camera, orientation, surfaceview

I just need some clarification with something regarding camera previews

In Android developer documentation they have this under the description for `setPreviewSize()`:

[DIRECT LINK](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewSize(int,%20int))

> suppose the camera supports both 480x320 and 320x480 preview sizes. The application wants a 3:2 preview ratio. If the display orientation is set to 0 or 180, preview size should be set to 480x320. If the display orientation is set to 90 or 270, preview size should be set to 320x480. The display orientation should also be considered while setting picture size and thumbnail size.

So in my code I am able to rotate the camera orientation to be straight, this works fine. So changing my orientation 90 degrees makes my camera straight.

Now I want a 4:3 image, one of my supported preview sizes is `1440x1080`, according to the block quote above this would mean I need to change my preview size to:

```
p.setPreviewSize(1080,1440);
```

But obviously this isnt a supported resolution for my device, so the app will crash.

here are my supported preview sizes, what do I do if I dont have a supported preview where I dont have the above scenario (block quote text)

```
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 1920 height 1080 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 1440 height 1080 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 1088 height 1088 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 1280 height 720 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 1056 height 704 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 1024 height 768 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 960 height 720 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 800 height 450 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 720 height 720 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 720 height 480 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 640 height 480 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 352 height 288 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 320 height 240 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 256 height 144 -----
iterator D/CAMERA: width: 176 height 144 -----
```

I need my image to be 4:3

Comment: Include the crash log in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I researched, you can only use supported preview sizes: [stackoverflow.com/a/8051114/6286328](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8051114/6286328) and [stackoverflow.com/a/6952604/6286328](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6952604/6286328). Perhaps your best shot is to get a similar suppored preview size (according to your required proportion) and test to see how it gets.

Comment: Was just about to post my crash log, I was thinking - so I get a int value which holds the rotation angle and if its 90 or 270 then use 3:4 instead? because after rotation it would be 4:3? I havent looked at my supported preview sizes yet to see if I have a 3:4 though

Comment: Yes, that seems like the way to go - setting your values to 3:4 or 4:3 according to orientation. If you don't have 3:4 or 4:3 among supported preview sizes, just go with the closest one and test it.

Comment: any idea how id get the closest one to 4:3/3:4 if I have no supported ones for them?

Comment: I guess you could get the supported sizes through the method https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPictureSizes%28%29 or check it here, apparently, it's a compilation of all supported sizes, just check it out and use the one that suits your needs, I can't guarantee it will work or that it's updated, but try it out: http://www.kirill.org/ar/ar.php. You could get the method sizes and print them maybe so you can see all that are supported and just choose one that suits you.